# How can I boot Ubuntu trial from USB drive on Windows 8.1 PC with SSD?

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, windows-8

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS onto a USB drive using the Universal USB Installer. Everything up until this point was fine.

I then restarted the computer, and tried to access the boot options menu on my laptop (Thinkpad T450s). First, it is written that I should "Press Enter to Interrupt Normal Startup". I tried this many times and could not interrupt normal startup. Maybe my laptop is booting to fast due to an SSD.

I then held the shift-key while restarting my laptop in order to access the new "Advanced Boot Options Menu" for Windows 8.1, but I did not know what to do next.

I've read many possible suggested similar questions, but I do not want to change my settings to boot to USB. I want to access the BIOS and boot from a USB manually.

How can I resolve my issue and access the above menu?

Answer (score 0):

I created USB stick containing Ubuntu 15.10.

Inserted the USB stick(pendrive) to USB port.

Turned on the computer and pressed F12 when Lenovo appeared on screen(My laptop is Lenovo G40-70) to enter boot menu.

I selected option containing USB and pressed enter.

This way you can boot from USB without changing boot order.

the button for entering boot menu may be F8 or other depending on your laptop